# Connect to private API Gateway from on premise using AWS direct connect

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am trying to call a private API Gateway endpoint from an on-premise server.  I have Direct Connect setup between my on-premise network and my AWS VPC.

The AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html#w2aac11c16c28c11) says the following:

> You can also use
>   AWS Direct Connect to establish a dedicated private connection from an
>   on-premises network to Amazon VPC and access your private API endpoint
>   over that connection by using public DNS names.
>
> You cannot use private DNS names to access your private API from an
>   on-premises network.

Here is what I have done:

1. Created an interface endpoint for API Gateway
2. Created an API Gateway
3. Set API to "private"
   [image: API]
4. Added the following resource policy to the API Gateway

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:<API_GW_ID>/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-<VPCE_ID>"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:<API_GW_ID>/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to call the API as follows:

[image]

It appears that there is an issue establishing a connection to the VPC endpoint.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE AFTER TRYING CURL:

It appears that I am now finding the VPC endpoint but getting a 403.  I have tried taking the resource policy off the API Gateway to see if a bad policy was the cause, but that wasn't it.  I tried using the `--insecure` flag and had no luck with that either.

```
c:\curl\curl-7.65.3-win64-mingw\bin>curl --insecure -v https://<vpc-endpoint-id>.execute-api.<region>.vpce.amazonaws.com/<path> -H 'x-apigw-api-id:<api-gw-id>' -k
*   Trying 10.42.189.101:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <vpc-endpoint-id>.execute-api.<region>.vpce.amazonaws.com (10.42.189.101) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Oct  9 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  9 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET <path> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <vpc-endpoint-id>.execute-api.<region>.vpce.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 'x-apigw-api-id:<api-gw-id>'
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: Server
< Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 19:49:24 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: 9c95b630-c383-11e9-b657-fbfc525bb250
< x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: evE-uHZWiYcF7Xw=
<
{"message":"Forbidden"}* Connection #0 to host <vpc-endpoint-id>.execute-api.<region>.vpce.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Notes:

1. My VPC endpoint has private DNS name DISABLED
2. I am calling the PUBLIC DNS name to access my API (vpce-blah-blah.execute-api.region.vpce.amazonaws.com)

Other sources I have used:

Tutorial for calling API GW VPC endpoint: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/
Tutorial for writing resource polic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html

Comment: Those "why this might have happened" suggestions are so vague and unhelpful that the creator of this tool you are using should literally be embarrassed to even display them.  I would suggest testing with the command line tool `curl` to improve the possibility of gathering a technically meaningful explanation of what is going wrong.  How to do that can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html

Comment: can you please confirm whether you have done below steps as well. 1. API Gateway private APIs only support TLS 1.2. Earlier TLS versions are not supported. 2. create an interface VPC endpoint for API Gateway execute-api 3. Create a Stage and deploy the API

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Michael-sqlbot.  A curl request attempts against three IPs behind the vpce URL and they all timeout.

Comment: @RobinVarghese TLS 1.2 shouldn't be an issue.  I have done steps 2&3.

Comment: That seems to confirm a routing or firewall issue.  The 3 IPs are within the VPC CIDR?  Next thing to try would be verifying connectivity from EC2 in the same VPC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the three IP's are withing the VPC CIDR.  I actually established a connection via cURL as you suggested (I was missing HTTPS protocol in my call).  I updated my question with new findings.

Comment: What was the outcome on this? Security Group issue? Did you succeed in your mission?